# Can't delete _JAVA_OPTIONS on linux

Tags: linux

After starting IntellijIDEA I get this:

[image: warning]

I tried to delete _JAVA_OPTIONS using `unset _JAVA_OPTIONS` but it is not working. Terminal still suggests to me _JAVA_OPTIONS, and I can't delete it as sudo.

```bash
sudo: unset: command not found
```

When I'm trying to start Java program, before program output I'm getting this:

[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: could you try running `$SHELL -vxlc : 2>&1 | grep -F '_JAVA_OPTIONS'` and confirm that `_JAVA_OPTIONS` is being set by the shell? replace $SHELL with your login shell.

Comment: Run, but nothing changed

Comment: it was not a fix. it was to check if _JAVA_OPTIONS is set by init scripts. could you also open a new terminal window and run `echo ${_JAVA_OPTIONS}` please? if the output is an empty line, you need to go through the IDE configuration because the variable is not being set in the system environment

Comment: It is not empty. -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true (Like in IDE)

Comment: this is going to take a while. but the other option will just be us trying to figure out one by one. so let's make this easier `grep -RF ${_JAVA_OPTIONS}" /etc/` and `grep -RF "${_JAVA_OPTIONS}" ~/` one of those should return a file. open that file and comment out the line which sets the variable. then reboot and try opening the IDE again

Answer (score 0):

I think you should edit your `${HOME}/.bash_rc` the following line:

```bash
export _JAVA_OPTIONS=""
```

Then logoff and logon again...

Comment: i think you meant one of `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`? possibly the later where env variables are typically handled

Comment: As you want, the file name depends on your distribution. Find on your own bash init script where your system initializes the environment and place there the line I suggested you.

Comment: tried, not working :(

Comment: I suppose this issue depends on your system confguration. Unfortunately we cannot help you anymore.